Access website using hosts due to expired domain
I have a website hosted on my homelab that I exposed to the internet a year ago and due to my registrar Freenom having legal issues I was not able to renew the domain, I haven't had time to focus on it due to being busy however now I am planning on taking the site live again.
My current problem is I am unable to access the website even though it's currently hosted locally as the domain has expired. I've tried mapping the domain using the hosts file however it just redirects me to the apache start page
Here is what my hosts file looks Like this is on a windows client
192.168.10.21 exampladomain.com

Here is the apache server config running on Ubunto Server 20.4
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName exampledomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@exampledomain
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/exampledomain
    <Directory /var/www/html/exampledomain>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>
    LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


I've disabled the SSL config as the certificate is now invalid
is there an easy way to access the website using the domain without me having to setup a DNS server?

That hosts entry looks fine to me. I would say to add the www version to the hosts file as well, but afaik the fact that Apache is serving up its start page to you means www isn't the issue here. To me this is looking more like a server configuration issue than a hosts file issue at this point. Please edit your question to include the OSes you're working with (presumably Apache is on Linux, but it could be helpful to readers to know what OS you're doing hosts file work on). Thanks!

added the systems and configs as requested

your hosts file should let you access the site without configuring a DNS server.  Does it not work for you?

it redirects to the apache start page, I figured it would have just taken me to the page but it doesn't

I seem to have fixed the problem by disabling secure DNS on Chrome
Settings >>> Privacy and Security >>> Security >>> Use Secure DNS
This is apparently not allowing the edits done on the hosts file which means chrome does not know how to resolve the domain
